# Cypress how to run before each spec file

Tags: cypress

I want to reset my database before each "spec" start. **NOT before each test**

I see that i can add code in `support/index.js`

```
before(function () {
    cy.exec('npm run db:reset')
    // This run only once before ALL the spec
})

beforeEach(function () {
    cy.log('RUN BEFORE EACH TEST IN EACH SPEC')
})
```

I want to run before each spec file.  I am using GUI and clicking "Run all specs";

I have multiple spec file and in each spec have multiple test.

UPDATE : My test in GUI failed because database wasn't getting reset. I tried running test in CLI and all tests pass. So does that mean in CLI it does run before each spec ?  Is it issue only in GUI ?

Comment: the `before()` should run once at the beginning of the testfile while `beforeEach()` should run before every `spec()`/`it()`. This should work while running the tests headless and headful. If it does only run in headless mode it seems you have a bug indeed. You can report that in Github: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues